# How to trigger the 'change' event if jQuery sets the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to trigger the 'change' event if jQuery sets the value from that button? Is it possible?

Code Snippet attached below:

```js
$(".first").change(function() {
  alert('something');
})
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".first").val('Button Value');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Change</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="" class="first">
  <input type="button" name="" class="button" value="Change">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking

Comment: The 'change' event won't fire if jquery sets the value, is there any reason you need it alerting on the change instead of the click?

Comment: oh ok now i know my mistake

Comment: Your jquery link is not working .... try this link      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: then Is there any way to alert if jquery sets the value ?

Comment: your snippet seems working, correct?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the question!!! Use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)!

```js
$(".first").change(function(){
    alert('something');
})
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".first").val('Button Value').trigger("change");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="" class="first"> 
<input type="button" name="" class="button" value="Change">
```

Answer (score 1):

It wont call the change event, may be you can call it manually like this.

```
$(".first").on('change',function(){
    alert($(".first").val());
})
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".first").val('Button Value');
    $(".first").change();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Use [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) which is raised when an  element value changes.

```
$(".first").on('input', function(){
     alert('something');
})
```

Comment: No.. Sir change event is also work in `input type="text"`

Comment: It will work but not all cases... `onchange` only occurs when the change to the input element is committed by the user, most of the time this is when the element loses focus.

Comment: Its working in `copy` `paste` also... it will not work in only one condition when we enter same value again...

Answer (score 1):

here is simple example

```
$(".first").on('input', function(){
     alert('something$(".first").on('input', function(){
     alert('something');
})');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to pop an alert on the page when the button is clicked, i.e. when the user submits some data to the form instead of alerting at the exact moment, you wish to pop an alert when the user clicks the button. Cause that is what i understood from your question. Maybe to do that all we can do is:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    alert("something");
    $(".first").css("outline", "1px solid #3366BB";
});
```

See if this helps any.